# Product of an M-matrix and an inverse M-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This problem comes from the book "Topics in matrix analysis" by Horn and Johnson.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two [$M$-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix). Show that $B^{-1}A$ is an $M$-matrix if and only if $B^{-1}A$ is a [$Z$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)).

I cannot figure out which characterization of $M$-matrices should be used to prove $B^{-1}A\in\mathbf{Z}\Rightarrow B^{-1}A\in\mathbf{M}$. Could someone give a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $B^{-1}$ is inverse positive and $A$ is semipositive to show that $B^{-1}A$ is semipositive. (Using terminology from that Wikipedia page.)

Comment: But $B$ - inverse positive implies $B^{-1}x\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$ while we need strick inequality. I'd guess that $B^{-1}$ should be irreducible or something like this to ensure semipositivity, no?

Comment: @Dmitry: $B^{-1}$ must have at least one positive element in each row; otherwise it'd be singular. So $B^{-1}\geq 0$ is enough to ensure that $B^{-1}x>0$ whenever $x>0.$

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. I cannot award you the bounty yet, but will do so asap.